# Were Lestat's special abilities developed with his vampire state, or was he already skilled?

Tags: vampire-chronicles, anne-rice

In Anne Rice's "The Vampire Chronicles", Lestat plays the violin and sings amazingly.

Were these abilities he possessed *before* turning or do vampires in her books develop amazing abilities, perhaps to attract humans? I'd like to know about the **book** canon rather than the films.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book "[The Vampire Lestat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vampire_Lestat)" makes it abundantly clear that Lestat could neither play the violin, nor sing with any great ability before he became a vampire;

> But I was in paradise again. And so was Nicolas though no decent
>   orchestra in the city would hire him, and he was now playing solos
>   with the little bunch of musicians in the theater where I worked, and
>   **when we were really pinched he did play right on the boulevard, with
>   me beside him, holding out the hat**. We were shameless!
>
> .................. [later]
>
> Something to do with the sentiments Nicki was expressing. Didn't make
>   sense. I tried to shrug it off.
>
> "**If you'd set out to play the violin, you'd probably be playing for
>   the Court by now,**" he said.

Lestat is, however an accomplished actor with excellent vocal projection, a regular churchgoer and the second son of an aristocrat so it's likely that he's had a level of choral training and almost certain that he can play *some kind* of instrument (he repeatedly mentions the harpsichord).

For the record, the vampire Armand *already* knew how to play the violin before being turned into a vampire (or at the very least owned a violin) since it was listed among the belongings he takes with him.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Vampire Chronicles" universe, all vampires are great mimics so they would obviously be good at any activity which wouldn't require one to understand the underlying concepts. With anything else they learn at a human rate. For example, Lestat is horrible with technology or scientific stuff because he doesn't understand what's behind it.

Comment: Sure, but could he not have possessed the skills beforehand?

Comment: Yes, according to all of the books, gifts/skills they possessed in any form as a human are greatly enhanced by the transformation. This is all explained in great detail in Prince Lestat, the VC novel released in 2014, where someone (I won't spoil it for those who haven't read it by revealing his relationship to the others other than saying that he was a child when the first vampire was created)  made a vampire of someone who was a medical researcher and apparently a genius when he was a human.